# How use a static properties on Gridview -> value

Tags: yii2

I have the :

```
class MyClass extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord

public static $myrequested = ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'];
```

How access value propertie os the myrequested  on the gridview ?

```
    [
        'attribute' => 'requested_mounth',
        'enableSorting' => true,
        'value' => ?????
        'filter' => Resourcerequest::$myrequested ,
    ],
```

if left blank it only returns the position of the array, and I need the value.

(the filter option work fine).

**EDIT 1**

Example of the array:

```
myrequested [
  0 => 'value1',
  1 => 'value2',
  2 => 'value3',
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add method getRequestedMounth() at class Resourcerequest

```
public function getRequestedMounthValue()
{
    if ($this->requested_mounth === null) {
        return null;
    }
    return self::$myrequested[$this->requested_mounth];
}
```

Then

```
[
    'attribute' => 'requested_mounth',
    'enableSorting' => true,
    'value' => function($data) {
        return $data->getRequestedMounthValue(); // OR use magic property $data->requestedMounthValue;
    },
    'filter' => Resourcerequest::$myrequested ,
],
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects I have used the code below:

```
['attribute' => 'final_cost',
 'format' => 'raw',
 'value' => function ($data) use ($staticArray)
 {
     return $staticArray[$data->id];      
 },
],
```